# Autodesk Maya 2012 x64 on Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: 11.10

I've been searching everywhere for a solution to this problem and I'm pretty new to Linux. I have followed the instructions on several blogs about installing Maya 2012 on Ubuntu, but when I try to run Maya via the "maya" command, I receive this error:

/usr/autodesk/maya2012-x64/bin/maya.bin: error while loading shared libraries: libssl.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Can anyone help? I have no idea what to do...

Comment: It would help if you could toss in some links on what tutorials you followed, it might give us some insight to help you.

Answer (score 4):

> **HOW TO INSTALL MAYA2012X64BIT in Ubuntu**

**Step 1**

Download Autodesk Maya 2012 Hotfix 4 from [**here**](http://usa.autodesk.com/adsk/servlet/ps/dl/item?siteID=123112&id=17478798&linkID=9242259).

**Step 2**

We have to install required packages. Open Terminal and paste these codes:

```
sudo apt-get install csh tcsh libglw1-mesa libglw1-mesa-dev mesa-utils libaudiofile-dev libaudiofile0 libaudiofile0-dbg elfutils gamin libxp6 libxpm4 libxt6 libxp6 libxmu6 libxau6 libxinerama1 libxprintapputil1 libxprintutil1 xfs xfstt ttf-liberation ttf-mscorefonts-installer xfonts-100dpi xfonts-75dpi alien
```

**Step 3**

Copy the downloaded `tar` file (autodesk_maya_2012_english_linux_64bit_hf4.tgz) in  `/home/Username/Maya2012_setup`

**Step 4**

Go to terminal and type:

```
cd /home/username/maya2012_setup
```

**Step 5**

```
tar -zxvf utodesk_maya_2012_english_linux_64bit_hf4.tgz
```

**Step 6**

For `i` in `*.rpm; do sudo alien -cv $i`; done

**Step 7**

```
sudo dpkg -i adlmapps4_4.0.35-1_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i adlmflexnetserver_4.0.35-1_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i adlmflexnetclient_4.0.35-1_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i maya2012-0-64_2012.0-327_amd64.deb
```

**Step 8**

Create a temporary folder for Maya:

```
sudo mkdir /usr/tmp
sudo chmod 777 /usr/tmp
```

**Step 9**

```
$ sudo sh -c “echo ‘setenv LC_ALL en_US.UTF-8′ >> /usr/autodesk/maya2012-x64/bin/maya2012″
```

**Step 10**

```
$ /usr/autodesk/maya2012-x64/bin/licensechooser /usr/autodesk/maya2012-x64/ standalone unlimited
```

**Step 11**

Export a couple of variables

```
sudo -i
export MAYA_LOCATION=/usr/autodesk/maya2012-x64
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/Autodesk/Adlm/R4/lib64/
```

**Step 12**

Pass the serial number and the product key to Maya

```
/usr/autodesk/maya2012-x64/bin/adlmreg -i S 657D1 657D1 2012.0.0.F serial_number /var/opt/Autodesk/Adlm/Maya2012/MayaConfig.pit
```

**Step 13**

Navigate to our Maya2012_setup folder

```
cd /home/Username/Maya2012_setup
```

**Step 14**

Create a file named `mayaInstall.c` in Maya2012_setup. Open it with your text editor and paste this line:

```
int main (void) {return 0;}
```

Save and compile it with this command:

```
gcc mayainstall.c
```

Now you should have a file called `a.out`. Backup your `/usr/bin/rpm` with this command:

```
sudo mv /usr/bin/rpm /usr/bin/rpm_backup
```

and replace `rpm` with `a.out`:

```
sudo cp a.out /usr/bin/rpm
```

**Step 15**

Type following command:

```
./setup
```

This will start setup, deselect DMM, backburner and go next

Use these serial:

```
serial      :666-42943644
product key :657D1
```

**Step 16**

```
cd /usr/autodesk/maya2012-x64/lib/
ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtiff.so.4.3.4 /usr/lib/libtiff.so.3
ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.0.9.8 /usr/lib/libssl.so.6
```

**Step 17**

Open `/usr/autodesk/maya2012-x64/bin/maya2012` with a text editor and add the command

```
setenv LC_ALL C
```

After this line

```
setenv LIBQUICKTIME_PLUGIN_DIR "$MAYA_LOCATION/lib"
```

**Step 18**

Go to terminal and type:

```
maya
```

Enjoy Maya and make cool effects and Animations.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like You need to install libssl. Go to Ubuntu software center and try to install

```
libssl
```

packages. However the issue may be that You need newer/older version of libssl to run program. The I would reccomend to download and compile libssl in the requested version and copy it into the folder, where maya.bin is located.