# How to install Autodesk Maya 2011 in Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, installation

I am getting an error when I run the command `maya` in my terminal:

```
usr/autodesk/maya2011-x64/bin/maya.bin: error while loading shared libraries:
libtiff.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I followed the link for [Maya 2012 x64 on Ubuntu 11.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/111443/), but I got stuck at the final step.
Can you please guide me to install Maya 2011 x64 on my 12.04 system?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try this :

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/Autodesk/Adlm/R5/lib64/
```