# convert rpm to deb failed install maya

Tags: installation, 11.10, deb, rpm, alien

When i use alien convert rpm to deb, it doesn't work. here is feedback.
maya version: hotfix4
Ubuntu: 11.10

> LANG=C rpm -qp --queryformat %{NAME} 'Maya2012_0_64-2012.0-499.x86_64.rpm'
>       LANG=C rpm -qp --queryformat %{VERSION} 'Maya2012_0_64-2012.0-499.x86_64.rpm'
>       LANG=C rpm -qp --queryformat %{RELEASE} 'Maya2012_0_64-2012.0-499.x86_64.rpm'
>       LANG=C rpm -qp --queryformat %{ARCH} 'Maya2012_0_64-2012.0-499.x86_64.rpm'
>       LANG=C rpm -qp --queryformat %{CHANGELOGTEXT} 'Maya2012_0_64-2012.0-499.x86_64.rpm'
>       LANG=C rpm -qp --queryformat %{SUMMARY} 'Maya2012_0_64-2012.0-499.x86_64.rpm'
>       LANG=C rpm -qp --queryformat %{DESCRIPTION} 'Maya2012_0_64-2012.0-499.x86_64.rpm'
>       LANG=C rpm -qp --queryformat %{PREFIXES} 'Maya2012_0_64-2012.0-499.x86_64.rpm'
>       LANG=C rpm -qp --queryformat %{POSTIN} 'Maya2012_0_64-2012.0-499.x86_64.rpm'
>       LANG=C rpm -qp --queryformat %{POSTUN} 'Maya2012_0_64-2012.0-499.x86_64.rpm'
>       LANG=C rpm -qp --queryformat %{PREUN} 'Maya2012_0_64-2012.0-499.x86_64.rpm'
>       LANG=C rpm -qp --queryformat %{LICENSE} 'Maya2012_0_64-2012.0-499.x86_64.rpm'
>       LANG=C rpm -qp --queryformat %{PREIN} 'Maya2012_0_64-2012.0-499.x86_64.rpm'
>       LANG=C rpm -qcp 'Maya2012_0_64-2012.0-499.x86_64.rpm'
>       rpm -qpi 'Maya2012_0_64-2012.0-499.x86_64.rpm'
>       LANG=C rpm -qpl 'Maya2012_0_64-2012.0-499.x86_64.rpm'
>       mkdir -
>       chmod 755 -
>       rpm2cpio Maya2012_0_64-2012.0-499.x86_64.rpm | lzma -t -q > /dev/null 2>&1
>       rpm2cpio Maya2012_0_64-2012.0-499.x86_64.rpm | (cd -;  cpio --extract --make-directories --no-absolute-filenames --preserve-modification-time) 2>&1
>       chmod 755 -/./
>   chmod: invalid option -- '/'
>   Try `chmod --help' for more information.
>       mkdir -/debian
>   mkdir: invalid option -- '/'
>   Try`mkdir --help' for more information.
>   mkdir -/debian failed:  at /usr/share/perl5/Alien/Package/Deb.pm line 299.
>       find - -type d -exec chmod 755 {} ;
>       rm -rf -

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=66859)

Comment: Could you please provide more information?  Your question is at least missing the command line you are using and your Ubuntu version.

Comment: Why would you convert an rpm if the installation should be done with a tar file?! See http://askubuntu.com/questions/111443/autodesk-maya-2012-x64-on-ubuntu-11-10 on how to install it. (and yes,I am making the assumption you want to install it and not are trying to understand how to convert rpm to deb).